# Does SharePoint Online have a Central Admin section like SharePoint 2013 / 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, central-administration

I've logged in to SharePoint Online in Office 365, but I'm not able to see Central Admin section. I want to know if a Central Admin section is available on SharePoint Online or, if not, how we can access the same settings that were available there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We dont have a Central admin in Office 365.

We have an admin site for SharePoint specific service applications, you can navigate to it via below url

```
https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com/
```

You need SharePoint admin permissions for that.

Tenantname is the `.onmicrosoft.com` name that you choose when registering for a subscription.

Nice overview of SPO admin capabilities- [Office 365 SP Online admin overview](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2014/06/office-365-sharepoint-online-admin-overview/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gautam and Waqas.. So that mean we don't have services stuff in SharePoint Online like Business Connectivity Services, Search Services etc..

Comment: Its is available, you have to go to the url I have mentioned in the in the answer and do the stuff there. Check updated answer for screenshot :)

Comment: Thanks Gautam.. last question..Can we deploy WSP code in SharePoint online.. I know we can use provided host but just want to clear my doubt..

Comment: Check this link - http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2016/08/sandbox-code-disabled-in-Office-365.html

No code wsp is possible. If the wsp contains dll, then its not possible. Also, by deploy if you mean `add-spsolution` and `install-spsolution` , then, thats not possible. But SharePoint designer workflows (no code behind) is possible.

Answer (score 5):

There is no traditional central admin in SharePoint online as we do not have full control in Office 365.

In Office 365 / SharePoint-Online we have the admin center where we have the all the options which Microsoft allow us( very limited as compare to on-prem.).
you can access it on this url `https://portal.office.com/adminportal`, from here click on SharePoint Under the Admin Center. if you have proper permission.
[image]

In SharePoint on-prem, we have full control in the environment that's why we have the central admin to manage the settings of SharePoint.